# highcharts $_post['value'] does not print chart values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql, highcharts

I wanted to create a highchart using a dropdown and the selected value should be used in the where clause in a select statement. But if I click on the button then the chart is printed but with no values (e.g. dbsize, or timestamp...). If I change the $db variable to "postgres" or something like that, the chart will be printed normally.

Here is the html code:

```
<iframe name="hideframe" id="hideframe" style="display: none;"></iframe> 
<form action="printchart.php" method="post" target="hideframe" >

        <div class="dropdown" >
                <select class="form-control" name="thenumbers" >
                  <option value="postgres">postgres</option>
                  <option value="template1">template1</option>
                  <option value="testdb">testdb</option>
                </select>
        </div>

<button name="Button5" id="Button5">click</button>



<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px">
    <?php include("printchart.php"); ?>
</div>
```

And here is the printchart.php File including js for highchart:

```
<?php
require("00connection.php");
$db = $_POST['thenumbers'];
//$db = "postgres";


?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#Button5').click(function () {
    

$(document).ready(function() {
        var options ={
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x',
        setSize: 400
            },
            title: {
                text: "DB-Size"  
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    <?php
                $sql =  $conn->query("SELECT  dbname,dbsize, epoch_time FROM dbstats WHERE dbname = '$db' ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
                foreach ($sql as $row) {

                ?> '<?php //echo (date('Y-m-d h:i:sa',$row['epoch_time'])) 
                    $date = $row['epoch_time'] / 1000;
                    echo (date('Y-m-d H:i', $date)) ?>',
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                ],
                title: {
                    text: "Datetime"
                },
                type:'datetime',
                labels: {
            format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}',
                }
            },
            yAxis: {    
                title: {
                    text: 'DB-Size'
                }
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: true,
                inputEnabled: false,
                buttonPosition: {
                 allign: 'left'
                },
                labelStyle: {
                    display: 'none'
                },
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                },
                          {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3m'
                }
                ]
            },
             tooltip: {
                //crosshairs: true,
                shared: true,
                valueSuffix: 'MB',
                xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
             },
             series: [{         
                 name: 'DB-Size',
                 data: [
                <?php
                     
                $sql =  $conn->query("SELECT dbname, dbsize, epoch_time FROM dbstats WHERE dbname = '$db' ORDER BY epoch_time;")->fetchAll();
                foreach ($sql as $row) {

                ?>
                    <?php echo $row['dbsize'] ?>,
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            ]
        }]
        };
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
    
 });   
</script>
```

The sql statements are executed normally in both cases (if i get the value using $_POST from the form or if I create a variable and initialize it with postgres (like $db="postgres") but if I assing $db=$_POST['thenumber'] then the chart will not be printed although the select statements are executed.

I hope anybody can help me :)

Here is the image:
[highcharts_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsNfZ.png)

Best regards

Comment: Start by checking what the actual HTML/JS code this created looks like.

Comment: It probably is posted but to the hidden iframe above. Why do you even have ` target="hideframe"` in form?

Comment: Could you share how your series.data output looks like?

Comment: Hello, I posted the chart how it looks if I set $db=$_POST['thenumbers']. I tried to set $db='postgres' - It works. But from $_POST it does not. I used the hidden frame because otherwise the form would link me to my php file but I want to stay on the main site.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel my series.data is ok. If I initialize the variable $db = "postgres (without getting the result from $_POST['thenumbers'], it works but only if I want to create it dynamically it does not print the chart correctly although the correct sql statements will be send to database

Comment: @blahy I use the iframe because otherwise the form action tag will link me to my php file but I want to stay on the main page.

Comment: @mymarcelsql Could you reproduce just your javaScript code and assign your PHP data and categories output to values? This will make us sure that everything is fine with the Highcharts.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel sorry for my late response. I don't know exactly what you mean. My categories output is stored in $date and my data output is stored in $row['dbsize'] so I call the variable with echo.

Comment: I am asking for JS reproduction of your chart where the categories and data output will be a hardcoded values which you received from your PHP code. Something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jsf9mxe2/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel sorry for late response. The output does not return anything:  var outputCat = [ <?php echo join($dbsize, ',') ?>];
var outputData = [ <?php echo join($dbname, ',') ?>];  although select statements are executed correctly: 2020-08-03 09:51:14.202 CEST [67254] LOG:  execute pdo_stmt_00000001: SELECT  dbname,dbsize, epoch_time FROM dbstats WHERE dbname = 'postgres' ORDER BY epoch_time;
2020-08-03 09:51:14.202 CEST [67254] LOG:  duration: 0.074 ms

Comment: So could you reproduce it in the online editor? I mean how the data looks like after the select statement.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel sorry I cannot publish my code. Above is how my data look: // Output from categories if i set $db = postgres:
// categories: [2020-06-19 13:07,2020-06-19 13:09]
// data: [5,7]

// But no Output if I assigned $db to a variable from $_POST altough select statements are executed

Comment: But your categories output is `[2020-06-19 13:07,2020-06-19 13:09]` or `['2020-06-19 13:07','2020-06-19 13:09']`? Because the categories format should be an array of strings.

Comment: yes that's right @SebastianWędzel I do not understand why I get an output If i set static variable $db to "postgres" but If i initialize the variable over $_POST nothing is returned. The php part is also being executed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand - is your problem related to using Highcharts library or getting the data from PHP?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel As I said I get the correct data If I set a variable called $db = 'postgres' (for example, static). -> The chart will be printed correctly. But if I set $db to my html dropdown menu (to get the input from a user) then the chart will not be displayed. (the sql statement is executed correctly but I think higcharts does not get the correct response). We can use another communication platform. Maybe I can share my code. All I want is to create a chart which prints the sizes of specific databases (database name comes frrom inpput from user) ( the values are stored in a database).

Comment: I am trying to help you from the Highcharts side, but I think that the problem is with getting your data. You said that `the sql statement is executed correctly but I think higcharts does not get the correct response` - I asked you to reproduce this case on some online editor where I will be able to see how your data looks like and how the chart data has been updated.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel First I want to say thanks for your help! Do you mean something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/mymarcelsql/dLx604jm/36/ But that is the code without php. I want to select a database and then print the size of the specific database. If I set $db = 'postgres' I get the output shown in the var outputCatDate and outputData but If i set $db to the form input then I do not get any output in the 2 variables outputCatDate and outputData altough select statements are excecuted.!